# Compilation netcoreapp1.0 with code which has Target Framework Monikers like #if !NETSTANDARD1_6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2, .net-core

I have problem with my project's dependency which has Target Framework Monikers like:

```
#if !NETSTANDARD1_6
```

and when I  compile for netcoreapp1.0 I have a compilation error, but netcoreapp1.0 support NETStandart1.6 , And I want to use this parts of the code in the app.

Answer (score 6):

When you compile for `netcoreapp1.0`, only the `NETCOREAPP1_0` symbol will be defined by default.

This means that you have two options: Either add the `NETSTANDARD1_6` define to `netcoreapp1.0` in your project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "buildOptions": {
            "define": ["NETSTANDARD1_6"]
        }
    }
}
```

Or change your `#if`:

```
#if !NETSTANDARD1_6 && !NETCOREAPP1_0
```